# Need help understanding Ruby: num_repeats returning numbers of letters that appear more than once

Tags: ruby

I need help understanding a small part of the code below. It is to return the number of letters that appear more than once in a string, all the while assuming characters in the string will only appear in lowercase.

```
def num_repeats(string)
  counts = []

  str_idx = 0
  while str_idx < string.length
    letter = string[str_idx]

    counts_idx = 0
    while counts_idx < counts.length
      if counts[counts_idx][0] == letter
        counts[counts_idx][1] += 1
        break
      end
      counts_idx += 1
    end

    if counts_idx == counts.length
      #add letters if not found first time. 
      counts.push([letter, 1])
    end

    str_idx += 1
  end

  num_repeats = 0
  counts_idx = 0
  while counts_idx < counts.length
    if counts[counts_idx][1] > 1
      num_repeats += 1
    end

    counts_idx += 1
  end

  return num_repeats
end
```

Might someone explain this part of the if loop in the while loop within the first while loop?

```
if counts[counts_idx][0] == letter
   counts[counts_idx][1] += 1
```

I don't understand the counts [ ] [ ]
I know they aren't 2d arrays from java Q.Q .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll let someone else answer your question, but I cannot let this go without telling you that what you have presented is horrible Ruby code. It looks like it was written by someone who cannot break away from a procedural mind-set.

Ruby allows you to compute the number of letters in a string that appear more than once quite easily.

**Code**

```
def count_of_repeated_letters(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:punct:] ]/, '').
      downcase.
      each_char.
      with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }.
      count { |_,count| count > 1 }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "Now is the time; for all good Rubiests; to ring in the New Year"
count_of_repeated_letters(str)
  #=> 12
```

**Default values for hashes**

`Hash.new(0)` creates an empty hash with a default value of zero. Let me explain what the "default value" means. First read the doc for the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

When Ruby encounters the expression `h[k] += 1` the first thing she does is expand it to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` has a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality is the current count, so it is incremented by one.

If `h` does not have a key `k`, she replaces `h[k]` on the right of the equality with the default value, so the expression becomes

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

That is, `h[k]` is set equal to one. If you are wondering why, in this case, `h[k]` on the left of the equality is not set equal to one, recall that this expression is actually *[syntactic sugar](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_syntactic_sugar.html)* for

```
h.[]=(k, h.[](k) + 1)
```

It is only the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) that uses the default, not the method [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

**Stepping through the code**

For the value of `str` above the steps are as follows.

```
s = str.gsub(/[[:punct:] ]/, '')
  #=> "NowisthetimeforallgoodRubieststoringintheNewYear"
```

This uses [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression to remove punctuation characters and spaces by converting them to empty strings. `[[:punct:] ]` is a *character class* that matches punctuation characters and spaces. Continuing,

```
t = s.downcase
  #=> "nowisthetimeforallgoodrubieststoringinthenewyear"
d = t.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "nowisthetimeforallgoodrubieststoringinthenewyear":each_char>
e = d.with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #   "nowisthetimeforallgoodrubieststoringinthenewyear":each_char>: with_object({})>
```

`e` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*. To see the values that will be generated by this enumerator and passed to its block we can convert it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [["n", {}], ["o", {}], ["w", {}], ["i", {}], ["s", {}], ["t", {}],
  #    ...
  #    ["e", {}], ["w", {}], ["y", {}], ["e", {}], ["a", {}], ["r", {}]]
```

This hash shown as the second element of each array generated by the enumerator will be built as the calculations are performed.

Continuing,

```
f = e.each { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"n"=>4, "o"=>5, "w"=>2, "i"=>5, "s"=>3, "t"=>5, "h"=>2, "e"=>6, "m"=>1,
  #    "f"=>1, "r"=>4, "a"=>2, "l"=>2, "g"=>2, "d"=>1, "u"=>1, "b"=>1, "y"=>1}
```

Lastly,

```
f.count { |_,count| count > 1 }
  #=> 12
```

See [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count). In this last step I could have written `h.count { |k,count| count > 1 }`, `k` and `count` being a key-value pair of the `h`, but when a block variable is not used in the block calculation (here `k`) is is customary to replace it with the local variable `_` or (here) `_k`.

**Alternative Method**

Here's how you could do it using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
def count_of_repeated_letters(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:punct:] ]/, '').
      downcase.
      each_char.
      group_by(&:itself).
      count { |_,arr| arr.size > 1 }
end

count_of_repeated_letters(str)
  #=> 12
```

Comment: I'm a beginner who's still trying to learn ruby ! Thank you for showing me this, and providing me with new information.

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing more information on what the code was supposed to do. It was to return the number of letters in a string that appear more than once. I thank you again for the detailed explanation of your code.

Comment: I edited my answer to conform with your clarification of the question.

Comment: The explanation your provided really helped me understand your code. Also thank you for providing me with ruby documentation to help understand your code.